# Incoherent stores

Tags: cuda

Why this kernel produces incoherent stores

```
__global__ void reverseArrayBlock(int *d_out, int *d_in)
{
    int inOffset  = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int outOffset = blockDim.x * (gridDim.x - 1 - blockIdx.x);
    int in  = inOffset + threadIdx.x;
    int out = outOffset + (blockDim.x - 1 - threadIdx.x);
    d_out[out] = d_in[in];
}
```

and this one doesn't

```
__global__ void reverseArrayBlock(int *d_out, int *d_in)
{
    extern __shared__ int s_data[];

    int inOffset  = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int in  = inOffset + threadIdx.x;

    // Load one element per thread from device memory and store it 
    // *in reversed order* into temporary shared memory
    s_data[blockDim.x - 1 - threadIdx.x] = d_in[in];

    // Block until all threads in the block have written their data to shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    // write the data from shared memory in forward order, 
    // but to the reversed block offset as before

    int outOffset = blockDim.x * (gridDim.x - 1 - blockIdx.x);

    int out = outOffset + threadIdx.x;
    d_out[out] = s_data[threadIdx.x];
}
```

I'm aware that second one is using shared memory. But when I look at indicies of d_out they seem to be the same in both kernel. Would you help me to understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coalescing requires that the addresses follow a "base + tid" pattern within a warp, where tid is short for the thread index. In other words, as tid increases, so does the address. Your comment calls this "forward order". In the first kernel, addresses are generated such that as tid increases, the address decreases, i.e. the accesses are in "backward order".

Comment: Note that the example code should only produce incoherent stores on Compute Capability 1.1 and early devices.  Starting with 1.2 devices, this access pattern is fully coalesced/coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start off you will need to understand writes to shared memory are much cheaper than writes to global memory.

With that in mind, let us say we are inverting an array 1->32

method one does this:
while writing
thread 1 reads from location x, thread 2 reads from (x + 1), thread 3 reads from location (x + 2) ... thread 32 reads from location (x + 31).

You could read this entire chunk of memory in 2 (if aligned) or 3 (if non aligned) reads, because the operations are done in chunks of halfwarps (16 threads).

While writing
thread 1 writes to location (y + 31),  thread 2 writes to (y + 30), thread 3 writes to location (y + 29) ... thread 32 writes to location (y).

Although they are writing to a contiguous chunk of memory, they are in reverse order. Unless you are using some of the latest hardware (And even with it I am doubtful), it will take 32 writes to perform the operation.

As for the second case, you are doing the 32 reverse writes to shared memory and 32 reverse reads from shared memory which is not as costly.

Now as you have already read the data in the reverse order, you can write to global memory in the correct order.

thread 1 writing to location y, thread 2 writing to location y+1 and so on.

The bottom line, you are saving time taken to perform 32 (metod 1) - 3 (method 2) = 29 writes to global memory.